# One polygon for multiple islands

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, polygon

So, I'm trying to draw google maps's polygon for every states in the US.

It's quite simple for colorado but it's getting more complicated for coast states or Hawaii.

I basically need to to draw multiple polygons in one. The idea is to add an opacity on mouse over. So for example when someone mouse over one of the islands of Hawaii, I want to add opacity on all the islands.

Any idea how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

A [google.maps.Polygon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polygon) takes an array of paths.

[example using geoxml3 to create a multi-part polygon of Hawaii](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?type=m&filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/us_states_HI.xml)